# Documentation for debconf VISIBLE?

Tags: debconf

The python3-debconf package (from Ubuntu bionic) installs a debconf.py module, which defines a `Debconf` class. The class does not explicitly define many methods, instead adding a generic handler for a list of command names, e.g. `get`, `input`, etc; these handlers issue the corresponding debconf command (`GET`, `INPUT`).

One element in that list is `visible`.  I cannot find any documentation for debconf's `VISIBLE` command.  Playing around with `DEBCONF_DEBUG` I discovered it accepts two arguments; the second argument is a question ID, but I don't know what the first argument is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VISIBLE` is deprecated since 1999 and no longer documented. Examining [the source code](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/blob/6822c5a433cc60170fcc8751c8de015d0f129fd3/Debconf/ConfModule.pm#L927) shows that its first argument is the priority. `VISIBLE` determines whether the given question is visible, returning `true` or `false` accordingly.

Instead of calling `VISIBLE`, [callers should use `INPUT` and check for a return value of 30](https://salsa.debian.org/pkg-debconf/debconf/-/blob/6822c5a433cc60170fcc8751c8de015d0f129fd3/debian/changelog#L6916).

Comment: This answer is correct, but the deprecation removed functionality. I was using (and in fact, am continuing to use) `VISIBLE` to determine if the templates file was successfully loaded (and falling back to a different file using `X_LOADTEMPLATEFILE`). `INPUT` does the right thing only if the field is unknown; once debconf knows about it, this turns into an actual query, which for some reason is failing on a missing Perl module.

Comment: I take it you’re using `debconf` *not* in the context of a Debian package’s configuration templates, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The idea was to simply be able to run `config` (which is in Python) to verify the questioning during development, and use the same script during dpkg. But it turns out, `VISIBLE` is not behaving as I thought it did, either, so I'm re-examining.